# Can an iBeacon notify a user's iphone without an app being installed?

Tags: notifications, ibeacon

I'm new to iBeacon's and am trying to understand one simple thing.

**Can I use iBeacon to display a notification on a user's iphone without a custom app being installed?**

For example, I'd like to build an app that sends out iBeacon messages to people that have an iPhone. When they get near an iPad running my app, it notifies them that they're near my "event", which of course is taking place at the location of my iPad.

Is this possible without the user having already installed another app that I've made to receive notifications of my event?

**Note that I'm open to any other tech or ideas that would make this work.** I know that Apple does this with their Apple Stores, but I'm guessing they can do this because they already have an app installed on the users device - probably the "AppStore" app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You typically need an app for any iOS notifications on seeing an iBeacon.  That is what Apple does for their stores.

The only exception is if you use Passbook to set up a notification trigger.  But you still need the user to install your Passbook entry.